# JMSPaymentCoreBundle : get error when doctrine:schema:update --force

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jmspaymentpaypalbundle

I'm trying to implement JMSPaymentCoreBundle but I get this error below.

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                              
The target-entity CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\JMSPaymentCore:PaymentInstruction cannot be found in 'CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\Order#paymentInstruction'.
```

Am I missing something in the doc ? Perhaps is there a mismatch with namespacing or the targetEntity value but I don't understand.

I also noticed that after my doctrine:generate:entities, the setter and getter seems strange.

Any idea ? I thank you for your help.

## Here is my full Order entity Class :

```
<?php
namespace CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction;

/**
 * Orders
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Orders")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Repository\OrdersRepository")
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="OrderID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    
    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JMSPaymentCore:PaymentInstruction") */
    private $paymentInstruction;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="OrderReference", type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $reference;
    
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="orders")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="UserID", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
    
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\CreditPackageBundle\Entity\CreditPackage")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="CreditPackageID", referencedColumnName="CreditPackageID")
     */
    private $package;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set reference
     *
     * @param string $reference
     * @return Orders
     */
    public function setReference($reference)
    {
        $this->reference = $reference;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get reference
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getReference()
    {
        return $this->reference;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setUser(\CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \CTC\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set package
     *
     * @param \CTC\Bundle\CreditPackageBundle\Entity\CreditPackage $package
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setPackage(\CTC\Bundle\CreditPackageBundle\Entity\CreditPackage $package = null)
    {
        $this->package = $package;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get package
     *
     * @return \CTC\Bundle\CreditPackageBundle\Entity\CreditPackage 
     */
    public function getPackage()
    {
        return $this->package;
    }

    /**
     * Set paymentInstruction
     *
     * @param \CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\JMSPaymentCore:PaymentInstruction $paymentInstruction
     * @return Order
     */
    public function setPaymentInstruction(\CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\JMSPaymentCore:PaymentInstruction $paymentInstruction = null)
    {
        $this->paymentInstruction = $paymentInstruction;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get paymentInstruction
     *
     * @return \CTC\Bundle\OrderBundle\Entity\JMSPaymentCore:PaymentInstruction 
     */
    public function getPaymentInstruction()
    {
        return $this->paymentInstruction;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have typed a wrong namespace syntax.

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JMSPaymentCore:PaymentInstruction")
```

The short syntax with `:` is not acceptable here.

Take a look at your other namespace declarations and fix it with full namespace.

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CTC\Bundle\CreditPackageBundle\Entity\CreditPackage")
```

Like this one.

*- Update -*

I believe, this should be the full namespace `JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction`